# Pygame Force Window Minimization

Tags: python, pygame

This question is regarding maximizing and minimizing the Pygame window.

What I want to occur is when my program calls a function, a separate application is opened. This part works perfectly fine as I have used Os.system, however, the second part of my goal is to have the python program minimize after this application opens.

I've looked around on the internet for some solutions but haven't had too much luck. I would love to know if there is syntax within pygame itself, or some other module, that can force the window to minimize.

Thanks a lot for reading and I look forwards to seeing replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [pygame.display.iconify](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.iconify) function.